# PHP's gettext with en_US locale

Tags: php, localization, gettext, po

I have a mo file

```
/data/lang/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/test.mo (translate foo => bar)
```

and use the following code to echo it

```
$locale = 'en_US'; 
$locale_dir = '/data/lang';
putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
bindtextdomain('test', $locale_dir);
textdomain('test');
echo _("foo"); // print foo
```

However, if I change

```
$locale = 'en_US.utf8';
```

Then it print the corrected answer, `bar`

And my system locale information:

```
locale -a
..
en_US
en_US.utf8
..
```

What would be the reason?

Comment: For what it's worth - I can't reproduce this on either Mac or Linux. Perhaps you could post the PO source?